# Floating DIVs and HEIGHT

Tags: html, css, css-float, height

**I want that the 2 divs with different content and size of content** will have the **same height.**

**They are floating to the left side**; the first has 80% width, the other the 20% width.

**Look at the full code** on http://jsfiddle.net/9gp6J/2/

```
<body>
    <div id="contenuto_body">
    <p>Etiam vehicula, nisl at venenatis elementum, augue velit malesuada ipsum, id gravida massa enim ut leo.</p>

    <p>Etiam vehicula, nisl at venenatis elementum, augue velit malesuada ipsum, id gravida massa enim ut leo.</p>

    <p>Etiam vehicula, nisl at venenatis elementum, augue velit malesuada ipsum, id gravida massa enim ut leo.</p>

    <p>Etiam vehicula, nisl at venenatis elementum, augue velit malesuada ipsum, id gravida massa enim ut leo.</p>

    <p>Etiam vehicula, nisl at venenatis elementum, augue velit malesuada ipsum, id gravida massa enim ut leo.</p>

    <p>Etiam vehicula, nisl at venenatis elementum, augue velit malesuada ipsum, id gravida massa enim ut leo.</p>

    <p>Etiam vehicula, nisl at venenatis elementum, augue velit malesuada ipsum, id gravida massa enim ut leo.</p>

</div>

<div id="ads">
    <img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/1676707/Happiness_is_only_real_when_shared-Christopher_McCandless-480x360-20100312_large.png"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `display: table-cell` rather than `float`. Take a look at the example: http://jsfiddle.net/26MGE/

Comment: Ok i tried this, it works properly for the height... but look at my code, there is gap between the start of the <div> and the first <p>.  **THE CODE** http://jsfiddle.net/9gp6J/5/
I don't know what it could be...

Comment: You can use `vertical-align: top` for your `table-cell`s to align the content to the top. http://jsfiddle.net/cangelis/fY9Gt/

Answer (score 1):

You set `height` to 100% on the `div#ads`, but it doesn't know 100% of what height...

If you set the `body` height, it will work, here is your update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gp6J/6/)

Comment: i can't work with 1000px (prefixed height) on the body.. someday my body will be 1200px, another day 800px and the height depends also by the device; small screens need more pixels to display documents... finally this can't work in resposive design

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery `.outerHeight()` to make the height of both objects the same but make sure you remember to input an ajax file.

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gp6J/8/